# Blender file all messed up after reopening UPDATE:: Problem fixed itself?

Tags: wireframe

UPDATE:: Opened the file again and now it seems to be fine?!? I had tried opening the file quite a few times before posting this topic, even closing Blender and opening the program again to see if it had just launched incorrectly.
However, hours after posting this thread, out of curiosity I opened the file again and everything seems to be fine now? I didn't even restart my computer.
I'm very confused, and I never saved the file once it started acting up, so it's not a new version of the file either (to the best of my knowledge). The main difference is that I tried opening the file again several hours later.  I'm very confused by this. I'll update this thread if the issue occurs again.

I'm a relatively new Blender user so I'm not sure what happened here.
I'm using Blender 4.0.1, and I'm on a Windows 10 PC, I'm not sure what other relevant info would be useful for troubleshooting.

I was working on a little animation in Blender last night just as a means of practicing the program. However, I was still in the modeling stage so the file didn't have any keyframes or things of that nature yet.

I essentially had a cube acting as a wireframe "cyberspace" with a wireframe road, and I was modeling a simple car that would be driving on it.

However, hours later I've opened the file again and now everything is borked. The file is completely messed up and unusable and I don't know what happened. I've worked on several Blender files before this and never had this issue, and I don't know what could have caused this. Everything looked normal when I saved, and the file wasn't even very complicated. Just some objects with emissive materials and "Wireframe" modifiers on them. I've tried turning the modifiers and materials off but that doesn't seem to change things.

So, imagine a cube that's been subdivided a bit with a plane inside, and a crappy little car in the middle of all of that (since I was still working on that part).
Now when I open the file, it looks like this.

[image: Blender viewport with a model where the vertices are scattered all over the place.]

This is with everything turned on

[image: Blender viewport with a chaotic mess of green and black faces covering the screen.]

I can't provide a "before" picture because I had no idea this would happen when I opened the file again.

I've tried to see if I can change a property or two about these objects but everything is completely messed up.

This was my first time modeling objects and putting the "Wireframe" modifier on them so if I had to guess, it might have something to do with that, though when I take the modifier off the objects that had it, nothing changes, and the car model (what's in the first screenshot) didn't have that modifier applied to it.

What happened? What could I do to prevent this from ruining more hours of hard work?